# Why does releasing a reference in Swift not cancel a subscription?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm curious, can anyone explain why releasing a reference to a subscription sometimes not cancel the subscription? I've built a simple example to show this behaviour:

I have a Combine pipeline defined in the `Adder` StateObject to do a simple addition of two terms into a resulting sum. I have set up a view so that it is continually feeding any valid changes in the TextField values into the `Adder` pipeline through the termA and termB published variables.

When the user taps on the "Compute Result" button, a subscription is made to the output of the pipeline, feeding into a `sink` that displays the result and should immediately cancel the subscription by setting the reference to the subscription to nil.

However, for reasons I don't understand, the subscription remains active for one more change. The user can change either term in the input TextFields, and the result will update in the UI.

Can anyone shed light on this situation, please? Also, note that I am not asking how to avoid this by implementing this differently. I know this code is not the way anyone would implement adding of two numbers. I'm just using this so we can have a simple example that has a combine pipeline in an ObservableObject being fed from Views, and receiving the output of the pipeline just once.

In fact, I already have some code similar to this where this problem doesn't happen (ie where the data is moving along similar paths, and the disconnect works as expected). What I don't understand is why it isn't working in *this* code.

I wouldn't be surprised if it were a matter of some reference needing to be made weak or something. Or that the release of the subscription isn't well defined and I shouldn't rely on it being immediate.

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

// Simple Addition Pipeline
private class Adder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var termA: Int = 0
    @Published var termB: Int = 0
    @Published var result: Int = 0
    
    init() {
        $termA
            .combineLatest($termB)
            .map { $0.0 + $0.1 }
            .assign(to: &$result)
    }
}

struct SingleUsePipeline: View {
    @StateObject private var adder = Adder()
    
    @State private var termA = "0"
    @State private var termB = "0"
    @State private var result = ""
    
    @State private var adderConnection: AnyCancellable?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Term A", text: $termA)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .onChange(of: termA) { val in
                        let a = Int(val)
                        if let a { adder.termA = a }
                    }
                Text("+")
                TextField("Term B", text: $termB)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .onChange(of: termB) { val in
                        let b = Int(val)
                        if let b { adder.termB = b }
                    }
            }
            
            Button("Compute Result") {
                adderConnection = adder.$result
                    .sink { total in
                        result = "\(total)"
                        adderConnection = nil
                    }
            }
            Text(result)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: I would avoid having any non-`ObservableObject` reference types like `AnyCancellable` in a view.

Comment: That seems a rather convoluted way to do `result = "\(adder.result)"`. I assume this is just a toy example? What is your actual situation?

Comment: Yes, it is a toy example. The question is, what is going on? How is it even possible for a second value to arrive at the `.sink`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've over-engineered this, just remove the ObservableObject and do the add in a computed property. Combine pipelines in `@StateObject` are designed for async pipelines but your calculator doesn't need that.

e.g.

```
var result: Int {
    return a + b
}

Text(result, format: .number)
```

Another issue with your design is multiple source of truths when there should only be one. i.e. you have the `@State var termA` in the View struct and another `@Published var termA` in the `@StateObject`. You need to just have one state; place it high enough in the `View` struct hierarchy that you can pass it down to the sub-views that need it. Pass down as `let` for read only or `@Binding var` for read/write. `body` will be called when the value changes, no need for objects or Combine pipelines.

Comment: I have *way* over-engineered this to do a+b. :-) It's a contrived framework to demonstrate the way the connections to the combine pipeline are behaving. I just want to understand why the disconnect doesn't work the expected way.

Comment: I understand but I think it's a waste of effort trying to use Combine to re-implement the same kind of change detection that SwiftUI View structs already provide

Comment: I agree. I wouldn't be investigating this unless I had a reason (It would take too long to explain fully. Short version: I need a singleton pipeline to be attachable to one instance of a view at a time, so on-the-fly attach+detach is needed, which leads here).

Comment: You can share a pipeline with `share()` and you can use `.onReceive` to subscribe a View to it. Then you don't need to worry about objects not releasing.

Comment: Thanks, Malhal. But it doesn't help in my situation, where I need to detach as well. I need to direct the output of the pipeline to a single (but not always the same) view. Anyway, as I said, I already have a workaround. I'm not asking for alternate ways of solving this, I'm trying to understand the anomalous behaviour exactly *here*. I appreciate all the helpful suggestions, still.